# WebBrowser control WP7 cant open page

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, browser

I have a problem with webbrowser control. There is some page on local server that is loading fine after redirect from login screen, when i use standard browser, but then i use WebBrowser control with predifined URI to open-it hangs after login and cant load the next page. What can cause such behaviour? Are there some limitations on script loading or smth?!

Comment: Is the issue on the server? (Assuming you can access logs to confirm if getting that far.) Alternatively, Have you profiled the traffic over the network (with Fiddler, or similar) to see what's different between the browser nad the control? Beyond that, with just youir description of the problem there is likley little more anyone can advise. The number of possible issues is so large that you'll need to provide more information to help narrow it down.

Comment: Sure, i understand that ive provided too little details. Tho i dont know myself what to tell. Dont think issue is with server, because native browser opens web resource just fine.

Answer (score 0):

One limitation on script loading is that scripts are not enabled by default:

Solving this is easy:

`<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="browser"
                  IsScriptEnabled="True" />`

e.g. see
http://ghazanfaralich.wordpress.com/2010/12/28/invoking-the-script-in-wp7-browser-application/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting WebBrowser property `IsScriptEnabled="True"`
and 
also while giving url other than path of some local html file,
set `UriType` to absolute.